# Robot framework test mobile app with appium, unable login app still show error Keyword 'AppiumLibrary.Input Text' expected 2 arguments

Tags: android, mobile, robotframework, appium-android

**Settings**

- Library     AppiumLibrary

**Variables**

```
${REMOTE_URL}   http://localhost:4723/wd/hub
${PLATFORM_NAME}    Android
${PLATFORM_VERSION}     10
${DEVICE_NAME}     868101048880709
${PACKAGE_NAME}     com.iremitx.light.remit
${ACTIVITY_NAME}    com.example.love.MainActivity
```

**Keywords**

```
Open test application
Open Application    ${REMOTE_URL}
platformName=${PLATFORM_NAME}
platformVersion=${PLATFORM_VERSION}
deviceName=${DEVICE_NAME} 
appPackage=${PACKAGE_NAME}
appActivity=${ACTIVITY_NAME}
```

Login app test

```
Input Text  xpath://input[@id="0804146915"]
Input Text  xpath://input[@id="123123"]
Click Element  xpath://button[@type="Login]
```

***Test Cases***

- TC01 Open test application for android
  Open test application
- TC02 Login app
  Login app test

kindly suggest me web or book or channel on youtube for studing automate test.

[image]

Comment: The error says that the 2nd argument is missing. E.g. the text that should be entered.  e.g. here `Input Text xpath://input[@id="0804146915"]` should be added text, - `Input Text xpath://input[@id="0804146915"]  my text here`

Comment: still error. kindly help.
AppiumLibrary . Input Text xpath://input[@id="0804146915"], Username
 ValueError: Element locator with prefix 'xpath://input[@id' is not supported

Comment: Then try to escape the equal sign with the slash. E.g. replace `=` to `\=`. So to have in the end `Input Text   xpath://input[@id\="0804146915"]   Username`

Comment: it shows error  
ValueError: Element locator with prefix 'xpath://input[@id' is not supported


Login app test
    Input Text    xpath://input[@id\="0920917049"]  Username
    Input Text    xpath://input[@id\="123123"]   Password
    Click Element   xpath://button[@type\="Login"]

Comment: Could you copy-paste failed keyword from the report just in case, to see where the error happened and what the parameters were actually passed

Answer (score 0):

You should use Appium Inspector to find and get the element locator you need.
The locators have a different structure than the ones in SeleniumLibrary.

Here is my example for an input element:

```
AppiumLibrary.Input Text    //android.view.View[@text='Email']/../android.widget.EditText[1]    ${username}
```